# Printer driver - ps, pcl, pxl, which one to choose?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

At work we have a Canon C5045i printer, for which Canon provides three PPD files: ps, pcl, and pxl.

Is there any one that is preferable over the others?
Is there any difference between the three?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PostScript and PCL are the most commenly used Page Description Languages, that means the low level language that printers understand.
PCL comes in different versions (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language), PXL being PCL-XL or PCL6 (Enhanced) being the latest and greatest version.
Most printers only support either PostScript or PCL (a specific or several versions of it).
According to it's specifications it looks like your printer model seems to supports both PostScript and PCL6 and 5c.

Generally you should use the PostScript driver if your printer supports it since this will give maximum output quality. The PXL or PCL6 driver can be used as alternative to PostScript if the printer has problems in PostScript mode, like interpreter bugs or low memory. The PCL(5c) driver will probably give you no extra benefit (perhaps the PXL is only b/w and PCL is for color, depends on the info inside the PPDS and how well your printer supports PCL6).

The "best" driver really depends upon what you expect of it: speed or maximum output quality and also depends on the input that is used (b/w or color and text/line art or photo). It could be that the PXL is faster for just text in b/w while the PostScript gives better output quality for photo in color, just do a small test to find out or use them both for different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same type of Canon C5045i, and the `PCL6-PCL5e-PostScript-UFRII_v21.30_INF_x64-UFRII_v21.30_Setup_x64` installer v21.30 does not work for me.

When I tried the Canon Generic PCL6 Printer Driver (v2.00), the printer worked fine but printed in black only.

After that I found the [`UFRII_XPS_V200_Win_uk_EN_02`](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100405802.html) (an XPS Driver) v.600 and it works fine, now I can print in color.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [the official Drivers for Canon imageRUNNER ADVANCE C5045i](https://www.canon.at/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-advance-c5045i.html?type=drivers&os=linux). There are three different versions available:

- CQue DEB (This installs the driver)
- CQue TGZ (if you want to select the driver manually)
- UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V5.50 (no not use this one, it's buggy for PDFs)

I have the [Canon ir adv C3830i](https://www.canon.at/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner_advance_dx_c3830i.html?type=drivers&os=linux%20(64-bit)), which is similar.

- UFR leads for several PDFs to freezing of the printer, do not use it
- CQue offerst three different [PPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description): [PCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language),[PS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript),[PXL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language#PCL_6_overview)

  - PCL might be the best option
  - PS did in my case only print in grayscale, however this provides the highest quality
  - PXL did only print in black for [Rashad Al Megrab](https://askubuntu.com/a/599075/676490), for me it worked flawlessly