# Differences between PostScript printing and printing using manufacturer driver

Tags: drivers, printing, postscript

What are the differences between printing to printers that have support for PostScript and printers for which the manufacturer offers driver packages?

To give a concrete example:

- The Brother HL-L2340DW laser printer does not have PostScript support (as PostScript is not listed under 'Emulation' at Brother's [support page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/spec.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2340dw_us_eu_as)), but there are drivers available through .deb packages available (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/546517/) question)
- The Brother DCP-L2540DW laser all-in-one does have PostScript support (as listed under 'Emulation' at Brother's [support page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/spec.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as)), in addition to the drivers made available through .deb packages

Given that both have linux drivers, would one lose any functionality with the lack of PostScript support?

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent this would depend on the specific drivers. If it turns out that it is not possible to give a generally appliccable answer, I'll edit the question it to make it specific to Brother printers

Comment: With my Xerox with generic drivers I could not print without margins and I could not see ink level and could not turn off the black ink conserving mode. But the printing itself had no difference.

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/136709/printer-driver-ps-pcl-pxl-which-one-to-choose